# Copy value formula from one field to another in different forms - LOTUS NOTES

Tags: forms, copy, field, lotus-notes, assign

Is it possible to assign to a field from a form a value stored in a field on a different form? Eg: txt_Name is on form_MAIN and txt_LastName is on form_SECOND.

I tried: ( on the Window Title on the form_MAIN ) ( the field "text_uniqueid" contains @Text(@DocumentUniqueId)

```
FIELD OldOrderNumber := @GetField("text_uniqueid");
```

and then I wanted to see if I can see the variable's value on the second_FORM:

```
@Prompt([Ok];"title";OldOrderNumber)
```

but the result is null.

In other words, what I want to do is: To copy the unique id of the main form to a field situated on the second form.

Comment: Florin, you need to define whether you are talking about documents that already exist, or new documents that you are creating.

Answer (score 1):

[@GetField](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETFIELD.html) can only get values from the current document. To fetch a field value from another document you need to use [@GetDocField](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETDOCFIELD.html) and supply the UNID of the document you want to read from.

> **@GetDocField**
>
> Given the unique ID of a document, returns the contents of a specific
>   field on that document. The document must reside in the current
>   database.
>
> *Syntax*
>
> `@GetDocField( documentUNID ; fieldName )`

Comment: Thanks, Anders! Btw, I want to copy the Unique ID of a document to a field situated on the second Document...So, the field on the second form (document) should contain the unique id of the first form.

Comment: @FlorinMihalache If the second document is a response-type document, then there will be $ParentUNID field that you can use. Notes creates that field when you create the new document as a response document.

Comment: Actually, that would be $Ref, not $ParentUNID, but since $Ref is a special data type it's not easy to work with.  It's much better to use the @InheritedDocumentUniqueID function.

Comment: @David : the second document isnt a response type document.

Comment: Then you will have to write the value to the new document or `@dblookup` it using some kind of key - `$Ref` is the only reference between documents you get for free in Lotus Notes.

Comment: Well, I did get the UNID of the main document stored in a computed for composed field on the second document. But when I display the fields on the second form on an embedded view, with the first column categorized containing the name of the field on the second form, the embedded view is empty.... When I exit the application, in the main form the embedded view contains the field values... In my case, both main doc and second doc are Document type...

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Doh! Don't know where I came up with that!